# Possible CKEditor bug with regard to image uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I noticed that if I set an empty `config.js` file in `app/assets/javascript/ckeditor` and restart the rails server the `File Upload` tab is no longer available. Remove the `config.js` file and reboot and it's back.

I discovered this while trying to set the default config and found that the mere presence of the `config.js` file causes this issue. I am able to replicated this on clean projects as well.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with version 4 or a rails issue or just my own lack of experience. I wanted to check here to see if anyone else was having the issue before I filed a bug, as I haven't found anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the tab is actually still there. If you inspect the set you'll see that it's been hidden with inline css.

Answer (score 0):

This issue on the ckeditor gem repo explains how to solve it:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/238

Just paste the referenced config javascript for the filebrowser into your config.js file and the Upload tab will return with full functionality.